# How to webscrape an obfuscated javascript site?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I would like to download all historical stock prices using a list of symbols written in a .csv file. The problem is that the site I want to download it from is an obfuscated javascript site and I fail to get the direct download link : http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/historical (download link at the bottom). For every page I would have to select the 10years option.

1. Is there an automated way to get all the direct download links
   despite the obfuscation ?
2. Is it possible to automatize the download task with let's say
   Selenium given that I have this download prompt every time I want to
   download something ? I would also have to rename the files since the
   default name is independant from the symbole (HistoricalQuotes.csv), how could I do it ?
3. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If a python solution is accepted, I did a quick script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()

quote = "AAPL"
period = "10y"

def get_csrf():
    url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/{}/historical".format(quote.lower())
    req = s.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(req.text)

    data = {
        "__VIEWSTATE": bs.find("input", {"name": "__VIEWSTATE"}).attrs['value'],
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": bs.find("input", {"name": "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"}).attrs['value'],
        "__EVENTVALIDATION": bs.find("input", {"name": "__EVENTVALIDATION"}).attrs['value'],
        "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED": ""
    }

    return data

url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/{}/historical".format(quote.lower())
data = get_csrf()
data['ctl00$quotes_content_left$submitString'] = "{}|true|{}".format(period, quote)

req = s.post(url, data=data)
csv_data = req.text

print(csv_data)
```

You can change the quote variable to whatever quote you want. The csv_data variable contains the data of the csv file. You can save this to a file or just use it instantly.

The script requires two libraries, requests and beautifulsoup. It works in both Python 2 and Python 3.